# How many days does Cage experience?

Tags: edge-of-tomorrow

In the movie Edge of Tomorrow how many days does Cage experience? Or to put it another way:

> How many times is Cage killed?

Comment: In the movie Cage dies 24 times on camera.

Comment: 13 times bill cage has died in the movie edge of tomorrow.

Comment: [Related SFF question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/63069/how-many-times-did-cage-relive-that-day-in-edge-of-tomorrow).

Comment: You have to count the times Rita died when he was trying to get her through the battle. She comes back, so obviously he died too.

Comment: and at the house he says he was learning to fly the helicopter. and teaching himself would take some time.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It doesn't appear to be discussed in the movie.

In the book the film is based on, [All You Need is Kill](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_You_Need_Is_Kill), he has **160** iterations.

There's an [interesting thread](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1631867/board/thread/230689934?p=3) over at IMDB you might want to peruse, where people have argued everything from 100 days to over 1000 days, to over 100 years! There isn't any common consensus on that thread (or indeed across the Internet, yet) on how long the loop lasted for *in the film*.

**Edit:**

In terms of deaths *actually shown on screen in the film*, Warner Bros. have a mash up of all his deaths [on Youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CRfPNZ0Xghs). Counting those shows **16 deaths** in the film. although many more must have taken place.

Comment: I was kind of hoping that somebody had simply gone through and counted all the separate days that are shown on screen rather than the theoretical number of days it would take for him to learn all the skills he displays

Comment: @APaleShadow Yeah, that would be cool to know! I'm sure someone will do that when the Blu-Ray or DVD comes out.

Comment: @APaleShadow But while this would be a start, It surely won't suffice the slightest, since *Cage* learns so much stuff that isn't shown, he probably needs far more days/deaths than shown in the movie. For example remember how he said that he was in this desolate house with *Rita* many times before, which wasn't shown at all.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson ... Also while at the house while we are watching, we see he knows about all of the mimics which are buried near by and that all of the different things which they have tried do not work. There is no way he would know all of that considering we see them arrive at the house maybe three times (I have only seen it once, so don't know the count). This tells me he has been to there *many* times. Also, we only see him go to the HQ to see the General once with Rita, yet they have *all* the moves planned out to get there. This would take *many* iterations to get it right.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson My question is quite literal I really want to know how many times, _in the movie_, that the day repeats as opposed to the theoretical number which is too opinion based to be a good question

Comment: @APaleShadow Oh, well in this case you might want to rephrase the question, since that is indeed an entirely different question (and one that could indeed be answered exactly).

Comment: @APaleShadow: Edited answer to reflect what I think you are asking.